# Iterating over a vector of functions in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, iteration

Is it possible to iterate over a list of functions in MATLAB? I'm trying to test different functions and this seems like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) and iterate over that. For example:

```
vec = 1:5;                            % A sample vector of values
fcnList = {@max, @min, @mean};        % Functions to apply to the vector
nFcns = numel(fcnList);               % Number of functions to evaluate
result = zeros(1, nFcns);             % Variable to store the results
for iFcn = 1:nFcns
  result(iFcn) = fcnList{iFcn}(vec);  % Get the handle and evaluate it
end
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to define your own functions it turns out you can do this, following on from gnovice's answer:

```
funcList = {@(x, y) (x - y), @(x, y) (x + y)}
```

Comment: Yup, works for [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) too!