# Matrix of symbolic functions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I would like to define a matrix of symbolic functions (not variables) in Matlab. In the workspace I would like it to be an element of class symfun of size N-by-M (where `N` and `M` are positive integers).

Comment: read  http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html  and http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/creating-symbolic-variables-and-expressions.html#bs_tekf-1

Comment: @mhmsa: Did you read the documentation? Using these pages I did not manage to put a symfun into a matrix. Everything I manage to create is a symfun returning a matrix.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create a matrix of [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) class elements (possibly for the same reason that one [can't create a matrix of function handles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5669454/2278029)), but you can create a symbolic function that returns a matrix of symbolic expressions:

```
syms x y z;
Afun = symfun([x+y y-z;y/x z-1],[x y z])
B = Afun(sym(pi),cos(y),z^2)
```

Of course you won't be able to directly access the elements of `Afun` until you evaluate it, though you can use [`formula`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/formula.html) to extract them:

```
Amat = formula(Afun);
Amat(1)
```

It is possible to concatenate `symfun`s into a matrix, provided that they all have the same input arguments (the arguments don't need to be used). However, the concatenation still does not form a matrix of `symfun`s – it just concatenates the formulas themselves so you still end up with one `symfun` as above.

Another option is to create a matrix of symbolic expressions, e.g.:

```
syms x y z;
A = [2*x    3*y^2   x+z;
     -y^3+1 sin(x)  sym('pi');
     3.5    exp(-z) 1/x];
```

which can be evaluated using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html):

```
B = subs(A,{x,y,z},{sym(pi),cos(y),z^2})
```

And normal matrix operations work, e.g.:

```
B = subs(A(2,:),{x,y,z},{sym(pi),cos(y),z^2})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to create a matrix, but a cell is possible:

```
c={symfun(x+y, [x y]),symfun(x+2*y, [x y]);symfun(x+3*y, [x y]),symfun(x+4*y, [x y])}
```

Maybe this is sufficient in your case.

Comment: I need a matrix but, as you said, I don't seem to be able to do it just by reading the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

If you for example want to arrange some anonymous symbolic functions in a vector you can do as following:

```
z = sym([]);    %declare z as an empty symbolic array

N = 6;          %array size

for i = 1:N
   syms(sprintf('z%d(t)', i)) %declare each element in the array as a single symbolic function

   zz = symfun(sym(sprintf('z%d(t)', i)), t); %declare each element to a symbolic "handle"

   z = [z;zz]; %paste the symbolic "handle" into an array 
end
```

Be aware that matlab treats z as an 1x1 symbolic function even though it contains more elements. 
z will still behave like a vector, so you can use it as a normal vector in matrix-vector operations.