# Matlab: creating an array of symfun

Tags: arrays, matlab, symbolic-math

I was trying to create a array of `symfun`, so that I may later access those functions and perform the `diff` operation w.r.t to the specific variables, I have searched and found the code as:

```
syms x
f = symfun([x1^2+x2-x3; x2+x3^2; x1*x2], x);
```

But is not the thing that I am looking for, this snippet is creating a `symfun` out of an array, but I need to create an array of `symfun`. So that if I have `n` `symfun` stored in an array and also have `n` variables stored in an array then want to create a matrix with the following rule:

```
[[diff(func_1, x1)    diff(func_1, x2) ...... diff(func_1, xn)]
 [diff(func_2, x1)    diff(func_2, x2) ...... diff(func_2, xn)]
  .
  .
  .
  .
 [diff(func_n, x1) .......................... diff(func_n, xn)]]
```

And here is my code:

```
function[K] = bigPopaPump()
x1 = sym('x1')
x2 = sym('x2')
f1 = symfun(3*x1+2, x1)
f2 = symfun(8*x2+5, x2)
funcs = [f1, f2]
xess = [x1, x2]
dummy_array = zeros(2, 2)
for i = 1:size(funcs)
    for j = 1:size(funcs)
        dummy_array(i, j) = diff(funcs(i), xess(j));
    end
end
display dummy_array
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean

```
syms x1 x2 x3
f = symfun([x1^2+x2-x3; x2+x3^2; x1*x2], [x1 x2 x3])
```

which returns

```
f(x1, x2, x3) =

 x1^2 + x2 - x3
      x3^2 + x2
          x1*x2
```

Similarly, this returns identical output:

```
syms x1 x2 x3
f = [symfun(x1^2+x2-x3, [x1 x2 x3]);
     symfun(x2+x3^2, [x1 x2 x3]);
     symfun(x1*x2, [x1 x2 x3])]
```

If you want an array of [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html)'s then you'll need to use [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). The reason for this is that a `symfun` is effectively a function handle. One must [use cell arrays rather than arrays to group function handles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5669454/2278029) too.

For your example:

```
syms x1 x2 x3
f = {symfun(x1^2+x2-x3, [x1 x2 x3]);
     symfun(x2+x3^2, [x1 x2 x3]);
     symfun(x1*x2, [x1 x2 x3])}
```

or

```
syms x1 x2 x3
f = arrayfun(@(fx)symfun(fx,[x1 x2 x3]),[x1^2+x2-x3; x2+x3^2; x1*x2],'UniformOutput',false)
```

returns

```
f =

    [1x1 symfun]
    [1x1 symfun]
    [1x1 symfun]
```

You can then evaluate the first function, for example, via `f{1}(2,3,4)`.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862353/matrix-of-symbolic-functions).