# Quad in a cell of handle functions

Tags: matlab, cell

I have two lists of functions, for instance: `log(n*x)`, `n=1:2017` and `cos(m*x)`, `m=1:6`. I want/need to construct the matrix product of these vectors and then integrating each element of the matrix between  10 and 20.

I have read this post: 
[Matrix of symbolic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862353/matrix-of-symbolic-functions)
but I think that it is not useful for this problem.
I'm trying to do this by using a loop but I can not get it.

Thanks in advance for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by assigning the appropriate vectors to `n` and `m` as follows:

```
n = (1:2017)'; % column vector
m = 1:6; % row vector

syms x;
l = log(n*x); % column vector of logs
c = cos(m*x); % row vector of cos

product = l*c; % matrix product
i = int(product, x, 10, 20); % integral from 10 to 20
iDouble = double(i); % convert the result to double
```

Comment: Thank you, m7913d.