# Vectorized or single line evaluation of function array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cell-array

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669454/iterating-over-a-vector-of-functions-in-matlab), a user asked about iterating over a cell array of anonymous functions.  I am wondering whether there is a way to evaluate a set of functions without the explicit use of a `for` loop.

As an example, the following code creates an array of (simple) functions, evaluates them for a fixed value and stores the results:

```
fcnList = {@(x) (x+1), @(x) (x+2)};
a = 2;
for i = 1:numel(fcnList)
    y(i) = fcnList{i}(a);
end
```

Is there a way to do this without looping?

Comment: I guess you could use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html) but I'm not really sure why avoiding a `for` loop matters in this case. `cellfun` might also be slower but I don't have MATLAB available to test at the moment.

Comment: You're right that there are probably few use cases where this would significantly speed up execution.  Still, it came up in a project and I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: To avoid a `for` loop or `cellfun` (which is more or less the same as a loop), you could define a _single_ function with _vector_ or _cell array_ output: `fcn = @(x) [x+1, x+2];` or `fcn = @(x) {x+1, x+2};`. Then `fcn(a)` gives you a vector or cell array cointaining the results.

Comment: @LuisMendo this is really useful. Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example, you could do the following using the [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) function:

```
fcnList = {@(x) (x+1), @(x) (x+2)};
a = 2;
cellfun(@(func) func(a),fcnList)
ans =

   3   4
```

Where I have created a handle called `func` which accepts as input a function from the `fcnList` variable. Each function is then evaluated for `a`.

If you need to pass a vector instead of a scalar, for instance `b`, you will need to set the `'UniformOutput'` option to `false`:

```
b=[3 4]
fcnList = {@(x) (x+1), @(x) (x+2)};
cellfun(@(func) func(b),fcnList,'UniformOutput',false)
ans =
{
  [1,1] =
     4   5
  [1,2] =
     5   6
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid a `for` loop or `cellfun` (which is [more or less the same as a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284027/cellfun-versus-simple-matlab-loop-performance)), you can define a **single function** with **vector output**:

```
fcn = @(x) [x+1, x+2];
```

Then `fcn(a)` gives you a vector cointaining the results:

```
>> fcn = @(x) [x+1, x+2];
>> a = 2;
>> fcn(a)
ans =
     3     4
```

If the results of each original function have different sizes you can define a single function with **cell array output**:

```
>> fcn = @(x) {x+1, [x+2; x+3]};
>> a = 2;
>> x = fcn(a)
x = 
    [3]    [2x1 double]
>> celldisp(x)
x{1} =
     3
x{2} =
     4
     5
```